# Adding certificate to internal load balancer in GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, ssl-certificate, internal-load-balancer

I have tried a lot to look for a solution, but I am not able to find one.
I Have my root domain in AWS `example.com`, we are on hybrid cloud.
We have service running in GKE. now we have setup `VPN` and we want to access website over the VPN which we have done.
Now all the internal load balancer that we have can be accessed over internal load balancer using `HTTP` via `VPN`. Now we want to add certificate on top of the internal Loadbalancer, GCP managed or tls

here is my ingress which create my LB but certificate is not seems to be not valid and challenge is not resolving.
what are the way that I can use to add certificate to the internal loadbalancer ?

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "gce-internal"
    kubernetes.io/ingress.regional-static-ip-name: something-internal
    cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: "letsencrypt"
    kubernetes.io/tls-acme: "true"
    acme.cert-manager.io/http01-edit-in-place: "true"
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: name
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
    app.kubernetes.io/name: name
    helm.sh/chart: something-0.27.0
  name: something-internal
  namespace: vault
spec:
  rules:
  - host: something.internal.example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          service:
            name: service
            port:
              number: port
        path: /
        pathType: Prefix
   tls:
     - secretName: something-internal-tls
       hosts:
         - something.internal.example.com
```

Answer (score 0):

Google-managed SSL certificates  aren't supported for internal HTTP(s) LB currently. You can refer to this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/ssl-certificates/google-managed-certs#:%7E:text=Google%2Dmanaged%20SSL%20certificates%20aren%27t%20supported%20for%20regional%20external%20HTTP(S)%20load%20balancers%20and%20internal%20HTTP(S)%20load%20balancers.%20For%20these%20load%20balancers%2C%20use%20self%2Dmanaged%20SSL%20certificates.).

You can actually consider this to manage and store SSL certificates as secrets using [Google Cloud Secret Manager](https://cloud.google.com/secret-manager/docs/overview).

You can also consider this workaround if you really want to to use Google-managed certificate to an Internal HTTP(s) load balancer configuration by uploading an SSL certificate from a certificate authority (CA). Please follow the steps below :

1. Use or generate a self-signed certificate or the acquired SSL certificate from a CA. If you prefer CA, you must follow the [guide/steps](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/ssl-certificates/self-managed-certs) on how to obtain a certificate.
2. Using your GCP Console or the "gcloud" command, go to your Internal HTTP(S) Load Balancer's configuration. It has an option to upload the SSL certificate and input other details (certificate and private key).
3. Setup your load balancer (Internal HTTP(s)) with your preferred backend services and health checks. Make sure that your SSL settings are configured to enable HTTP(s) traffic.

Comment: what you share is for Application LB which is External.
my concern and question is around the internal Load balancer

Comment: thanks @srividya No it has not , What I understand and and have done is created self signed certificates and attached that to load balancer and that way it is working, there is a overhead that we need to add CA to each VM or user who access the service over vpn. I am looking for something mature solution.

Comment: If you use a **global HTTPS load balancer**, SSL certificates are not required on individual VM instances, because traffic between LB and backend instances is encrypted by default. If you want to encrypt internal traffic between your VMs, you have to use self signed certificates and specify them in the regional HTTP proxy.

Comment: @WaseemMir, Have you tried the above global HTTPS load balancer. Did that solution work for you? If not, I am happy to assist further.

Comment: NO , you don't understand my question, you are answer in dark, and I would not appreciate that 
after ready a lot abt it I concluded that we need o create self signed certificate to make it work and it is working fine.